# Unable to change the text to "Tax Invoice" insted of "Invoice" in code igniter webapp

Tags: php, codeigniter

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwPrN.png) I need to change the text to tax invoice. I don't know much of Codeigniter. Here is the code.

```
<!-- Invoice Company Details -->
<div id="invoice-company-details" class="row mt-2">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-xs-center text-md-left">
       <p></p>
       <img src="<?php $loc = location($invoice['loc']);
       echo base_url('userfiles/company/' . $loc['logo']) ?>" class="img-responsive p-1 m-b-2" style="max-height: 120px;">
       <p class="ml-2"><?= $loc['cname'] ?></p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-xs-center text-md-right">
       <h2><?php echo $this->lang->line('INVOICE') ?></h2>
       <p class="pb-1"> <?php echo $this->config->item('prefix') . ' ' . $invoice['tid'] . '</p>
          <p class="pb-1">' . $this->lang->line('Reference') . ':' . $invoice['refer'] . '</p>'; ?>
             <ul class="px-0 list-unstyled">
                <li><?php echo $this->lang->line('Gross Amount') ?></li>
                <li class="lead text-bold-800"><?php echo amountExchange($invoice['total'], 0, $this->aauth->get_user()->loc) ?></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
    <!--/ Invoice Company Details -->
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow... go to the languages folder and sub-folder. Open *_lang.php file and find your text key want to be changed like `$lang['INVOICE'] = "INVOICE"` to `$lang['INVOICE'] = "tax invoice"`. NO need to change in code. Your language key is already defined in codes. just go to different languages file which are in used and updat the text against that language key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invoice title is set in this line:

`<h2><?php echo $this->lang->line('INVOICE') ?></h2>`

To change this content, go to: `application/language/english` and find the language files in there, and search for the string `INVOICE` in all language files. Change it there accordingly.

(Of course, there may be other languages specified other than English asd well - if your application is multilingual - in that case, you need to check for this string in all language folders.)